# Spring boot http security jwt key from file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

Currently I am using the following configuration to authenticate add the key for the jwt that decrypts the authorization token on each request:

```
security:
   oauth2:
      resource:
         jwt:
            keyValue: test
```

And the below is the http security configuration that uses this to only allow specific endpoints

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "securityEnabled")
public class ResourceServiceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {     
    httpSecurity
        // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
        .csrf().disable()

        // don't create session
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

        .authorizeRequests()

        // allow anonymous requests to root
        .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/" ).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasAuthority("admin");
}
}
```

What I am trying to do is, instead of getting this key value from the application.yml, somehow add this key value during the startup of the service, grabbing it from the filesystem and letting the resource server configuration deal with the rest for me. Endless googling has lead me nowhere, although my best guess would be to autowire the authentication manager and override the method, but I don't think that works with http security in spring.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you would want to do what's detailed in [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

For example have a file like `yourfile.properties`, containing

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value=yourkey
```

and then starting your app with `--spring.config.location=yourfile.properties` parameter.